# Why I can't add a tag alone, when the question has a plunker

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Today I tried to add the `ng-grid` tag to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836381/popover-doesnt-work-with-ng-grid), since the question is related to `ng-grid`.

When I'm adding the tag, it shows a warning due to the plunker link.

> [image: Tag_Plunker_Issue]

As per the shown warning I modified the plunker link (changed the plunker URL http://plnkr.co/edit/pucSb6?p=preview to [`plunk`](http://plnkr.co/edit/pucSb6?p=preview) shorten), and nothing more to improve on that question.

But [my suggestion was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8492306).

Is I can't add the tag alone, if the plunker not allowing to submit?

For this question, if I want to add the tag alone, what scenario do I have to follow?

Comment: @BoltClock the link was preserved and condensed in the actual suggestion as [`plunk`](link to plunker)

Comment: @BoltClock: My question is, what is the way to suggest the edit with the plunker link?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Looks like the diff masked the link in that case.

Comment: @BoltClock He also wrapped ng-grid with code tags so doesn't that circumvent the must be accompanied by code requirement?

Comment: @NathanOliver: That and the word plunk, yes. I've never seen someone so nonchalant about having circumvented the quality filter all for the sake of one tag ("As per the warning I put random stuff in code tags and nothing more").

Comment: What do you mean by *"Is I can't add the tag alone, if the plunker not allowing to submit?"*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was one of the users who rejected that suggested edit.  I left a custom reason for the rejection:

> The formatting improved, but you did not edit in the code provided in the off-site demo (plunker).

I felt that you needed to do more for the post.  The post lacked any code, but the code was provided off-site.  You edited the rest of the post (which IMO were minor improvements but not absolutely necessary), but **you failed to address the most important problem with the post: the lack of (readily accessible) code**.  You should have gone to the plunker and edited in the relevant parts of the code from the plunker into the question.

Comment: My intention is to add the tag only, since the plunker link is not allowing to suggest the edit, so only i modified it. Is my suggestion was rejected only for the plunker change?

Comment: @Arulkumar it was rejected because your edit was incomplete.

Comment: In any way - the restriction and what is wanted is soooo unnecessary that ... I don't know what to say ...

Answer (score 6):

You should have edited the code in instead of cheating the rules.  If all you wanted to do was add the tag and it wouldn't let you, you should just walk away.

When doing suggested edits you should fix as much as possible.  The reason for this is you are consuming other peoples time by reviewing your edit.  If all there was to be edited was trivial that is one thing but in this case there was a major edit that needed to be done.

If you do a lot of tag only edits I would suggest you wait until you have more than [2K reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) so your edits become actual edits and not suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

We do not like link-only answers, but link-only questions are not really better. Edits are here to improve posts and take them to an acceptable quality level. The problem here is that even after your edit, the post is still link-only, and as such poor quality.

So the rule is : if you cannot change a post into an acceptable quality one, just move away - at least until you have reached the 2K limit.