# Why can't questions with links to sites like plunkr be edited without the restriction that they must be accompanied by code

Tags: support, edits

I'm trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452040/angularjs-sharing-methods-between-controllers) but I can't because of the restriction that posts containing links to plunkr must be accompanied by code.  Apparently the question got asked before this restriction got put in place.  Surely such questions should be able to be edited without this restriction.

I did search for the following and found no results: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=editing+questions+with+links+to+plunkr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=editing%20questions%20with%20links%20to%20plunkr)  Sorry if it is a duplicate nevertheless

Comment: Related problem: [Ban on the word “problem” for titles makes it difficult to edit existing posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268546/2675154)

Comment: Related: [Why i can't add a tag alone, when the question having a plunker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297251/why-i-cant-add-a-tag-alone-when-the-question-having-a-plunker)

Comment: Somebody decided to delete a comment of mine I'll try to express it more nicely.  I think people are being myopic and are reacting to the question I was trying to edit, rather than the actual issue I raise.  What if the original question were otherwise a high quality question -- should a potential editor really have to go through the trouble of sifting through a plunkr to try to post relevant code, when their edits might have nothing to do with the code itself?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I'm having a hard time imagining a high quality question that has a plnkr link but no code.

Comment: @ryanyuyu You have been a member here only a year, there are lots of posts older than that where you were not required to have code when you include a link to plunkr or other such sites.  This is plainly noted in my question "the question got asked before this restriction got put in place"

Comment: @GeorgeJempty and that's relevant how?  You haven't actually provided an example of the mystical beast that is a "good question with a plunker that doesn't include code"

Comment: @ryanyuyu In the Dark Ages before you joined StackOverflow a link to a site such as plunkr was generally considered sufficient.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty and we have new standards.  So that's why.  And the current standards ask that code exist when an off-site demo does.

Comment: The point of editing a question is to improve the quality of the question. Moving external code snippets to the post is one such improvement. Just because the question is old, doesn't mean it doesn't have to follow the newer rules.

Comment: I saw the last paragraph (see answer below) and intended to remove that.  Why should I be required to do anything more?  Again, if it happens to me again, I'm just not going to edit the question whatsoever -- I do have other things to do besides SO after all.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to edit that post, then you should probably be addressing what appears to be *its most significant problem* in that the code isn't in the question.  Copy the code to the question if you're trying to improve it; its probably the best improvement you could make.

Comment: This, and removing that obnoxious last paragraph. So tempting to add a late comment on that.

Comment: @Jongware That last paragraph is what I was trying to remove.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the question as suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452040/angularjs-sharing-methods-between-controllers , which I think shows how bringing the code into the question improves it. Also got rid of the complaint at the end.